# How can I work out why a specific version of a library is in the dependencies?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, glibc, libc

I'm building a large C++ project using cmake on ubuntu 12.04 and then taking the resulting binary package and trying to run it on ubuntu 11.04. However the program fails saying it needs glibc version 2.14 but can only find up to version 2.13.
How can I find out exactly why glibc=>2.14 is required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike most libraries, glibc versions its symbols.  Every symbol is tagged with a value (e.g. "GLIBC_2.3.4") representing the version of the library where it's interface was last changed.  This allows the library to contain more than one version of a given symbol and support binaries compiled against older versions while preserving the ability to evolve.  You can see this detail with `objdump -T /lib/libc.so.6`.

Basically, something in your app was linked against a symbol that was changed since 11.04.  Try `objdump -T` on your binary and see what tags it's looking for.

But broadly, backwards compatibility doesn't work like that in Linux.  If you want something to run on older software, you should build it on older software.  It's possible to set up a backwards-compatible toolchain on more recent distros, but it's not the default.

Comment: is forwards compatibility easier? as in if i build on 10.04 will the binaries be likely to run on 12.04 (primarily thinking about glibc and ignoring anything horrible like ffmpeg)

Comment: The confusing part was that this program builds and runs on 11.04 fine, just the binaries built on 12.04 won't work on 11.04.

Comment: OK I've found that the dependency is on memcpy().
Seems that this function was changed in glibc 2.14. Considering that we do build and run this application on 11.04 etc and this we're happy with the older version of memcpy(), what would you suggest be a good course of action?

Comment: Yes, the 10.x build should run out of the box on 12.x.

Comment: Exactly: forwards compatibility at the glibc level is 100% guaranteed.  Unless it's a severe hardship (i.e. targetting a *really* old distro) the simplest thing is to just build on 10.04 Lucid, which is an LTS still under support.  If you absolutely have to build on 12.04, you could build your own glibc from older sources and link against that.

Answer (score 0):

When you build your C++ project, it will link to the version of the glibc library on your 12.04 installation. What are the linker options in your build command?

Without knowing exactly what you are building, I'd say you might be better off building on 11.04 and then running on 12.04.